# How to create bean with generic type?

Tags: java, spring

There is Spring Bean configurer  class as:

```
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

 @Bean
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, QueueSipInfo> getQueuesList() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }
    
 @Bean
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, DaemonSipInfo> getDaemonsList() {
        return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }
```

and  these beans are injected to controller class as:

```
    @RestController
    public class InfoController {
    
        @Autowired
        private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, QueueSipInfo> queueList;
    
        @Autowired
        private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, DaemonSipInfo> daemonList;
```

The amount of entity classes may be more than two and the idea of ​​writing the same code for every (QueueSipInfo, DaemonSipInfo, etc.) entity doesn't seem very elegant. Is it possible to replace many methods by only one with generic type? How to inform Spring about what entity it should use?

Something like this:

```
@Bean
public <T> ConcurrentHashMap<String, T> getEntityList() {
    return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}
```

Comment: You could use one abstract and several concrete [`FactoryBean`s](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean). What's the point of those maps in the first place, though? Perhaps it would be more convenient for them to simply be fields of a singleton bean instead